# How should I implement the mini player like spotify using React Native?

Tags: react-native, spotify

[image: the mini player]

I am thinking of using **Bottom Tab Bar** or a **Bottom Sheet**, but I am unable to make it visible on all screens of my Stack Navigator.

Any idea or suggestion will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use redux, and modal from react-native and wrap your component to the root.
if you use component in the root then you can use it anywhere with the help of redux.

Comment: i will give redux a try then (beginner here)

Comment: Can you explain what exactly should I do in redux stuff?

Comment: Redux is state management technique, it gives a central state which can be used anywhere in the application in any component. Suppose you want to show music player modal but you gonna click on different component, in this case the openmodal state needs to be changed to true.